# Query on Contract JAVA API Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am analyzing the Fabcar Java Project in Hyperledger Fabric.
Below are the dependencies in project. snippet from pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hyperledger.fabric</groupId>
         <artifactId>fabric-gateway-java</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
         <version>1.4.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
         <version>5.4.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
         <version>5.4.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
         <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
         <version>3.12.2</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

I am able to run the Programs in it. like

```
EnrollAdmin.main(null);
RegisterUser.main(null);
ClientApp.main(null);
```

Then I wanted to write my own smart contract from scratch.so started research/analysis and stumbled upon
[Video By Hyperledger Foundation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaSM5E7XWu4&list=PL0MZ85B_96CH7wvtrRzV7SvtRY0sI0DEg&index=2&t=2017s)

here in this video , presenter said every smart contract has to extend from Contract class.
Contract class contains methods like

```
beforeTransaction()
afterTransaction()
 createContext()
```

etc

so I searched Contract class in my Java workspace and found different methods present in it.
such as

```
Transaction createTransaction(String name);
submitTransaction(String name, String... args) 
evaluateTransaction(String name, String... args)
```

So my questions

1. has Contract class upgraded and I am watching old tutorials or I am referring to OLD APIs ?
2. Also I found that , there is a dependency fabric-chaincode-shim 2.2.4 API, which  contains the methods which matches with Video tutorial.

   package: org.hyperledger.fabric.contract

   interface: ContractInterface

Do i have to import this dependency or my existing Contract interface(org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.Contract) enough to write a new smart contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two coding aspects to writing an application for Fabric. One is the Smart Contract (also referred to as chaincode). The other is the client side application that will send in transaction requests that result in functions in the Smart Contract being executed.

Taking the SmartContract first, that will extend the Contract Interface, and then you'll write various transaction functions (for example createAsset).

To 'run' these transaction functions a client application needs to call submit or evaluate transaction. Only if a transaction function is submitted will changes be made to the ledger. Evaluate is therefore really just a query.

In summary there are two APIs that you need to use - one for the Contract and one for the Client Application.

Answer (score 0):

createContext(), beforeTransaction() and afterTransaction() methods are part of the Hyperledger Fabric [contractapi](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-java/release-2.2/api/org/hyperledger/fabric/contract/ContractInterface.html#afterTransaction(org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.Context,java.lang.Object)). These methods are available to use in chaincode. createTransaction​(), submitTransaction() and evaluateTransaction() are part of the [application gateway](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/release-2.2/org/hyperledger/fabric/gateway/Contract.html#createTransaction(java.lang.String)). Application gateway package is used to interact with the Fabric network. You can invoke/query chaincode using application gateway. Samples for both are available in [fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples). For more information, refer [official documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sdk_chaincode.html#fabric-contract-apis-and-application-apis).